# How to upload a file in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, files

I'm a brand new Drupal user and I just installed and started configuring a Drupal 8 instance.  I've had no problem tweaking the theme, and creating text content, but I can't seem to find the button to upload a file.  I doesn't exist on *admin/content/files* where I would expect it, and Googling quickly points me to modules I could include.

I was hoping to upload a few images to use on some of my "basic page" content entries.

Is there not a simple "file upload" button in this CMS?

Comment: Define "simple" :) What do you plan to do with the file once it's uploaded? Are you hoping to attach it to a node (content page) for example?

Comment: @Clive Yes, I was hoping to upload a few images to use on some of my "basic page" content entries.  I think I found where you can create a new content type with a file attachment, which is cool, but not what I need for this simple case.

Answer (score 3):

"Content entity" types like nodes (content) are field-able, so you can choose what data are attached to them.

The "basic page" content type only comes with a body field out of the box, but it's a cinch to add new ones:

1. Visit /admin/structure/types
2. Click "Manage fields" for the "basic page" type
3. You'll see a list of the fields currently attached to the content type. Click "Add field"
4. Select a field type; "Image" would probably make most sense for your needs
5. Follow the rest of the wizard and choose suitable values (should all make sense)

When you visit the node add/edit page for a "basic page", you'll see the new field, and you'll be able to upload your images.

Next you'll probably want to visit the "Manage display" tab to choose how the images are rendered, and the "Manage form display" tab to choose which widget is used.

Comment: I don't have "Manage display", at least I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you install and enable [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) if you haven't already.

Out of the box for Articles, there are two options where you can add images (see screenshot)

[image]

Now, basic page does not come with the bottom option, but you can easily add it.

Go to basic page manage fields.

[image]

Click on Add Field. Now you can re-use an existing image field (as seen/used in Articles)

[image]

OR create a new image field

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The question is not how to add a file to another content type... I think the issue is that there doesn't seem to be a way to upload a stand alone file as there is on Drupal 7[image]

Comment: This is not available for Drupal 8, any idea if this can be enabled explicitly as such? Thanks!

Comment: There is an open bug which is postponed: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2454311. Also it talks of "Add a file" feature only when the table is empty. This really would be a very good feature if available.